# pam ftp send upon successful login

Tags: pam

I've researched this feature extensively and need help.  PAM is a difficult authentication program for me to thoroughly understand although I'm learning.

We have the option of running either ProFTPD or pure-ftpd on a VPS hosted by hostgator. The OS is CentOS release 5.11. I have complete access to the server.  Our goal is to send an email upon successful FTP login by a user.  I've successfully used a script which is run by PAM for notification emails dispatched upon successful SSH logins and need to modify it for successful FTP logins.  That script which is amazing works fine with ssh (but we need ftp as I've mentioned) and can be viewed here:

http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html

Before I even try to wrap my head around why this script does not work using FTP, despite PAM working on our VPS (for at least ssh), can someone chime in with some theory as to why this is not working at all.  I.E., maybe I'm way off base with this idea and it can't work with FTP and PAM in which case I'll just drop this approach.  However, when I read configuration settings, etc., on using PAM with these two FTP programs, they seem to indicate this should work.

Additionally, running the following code which is supposed to test for PAM-enabled applications does not return FTP.

```html
ldd /{,usr/}{bin,sbin}/* | grep -B 5 libpam | grep '^/'
```

Any suggestions or help from gurus would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found solutions.  The answer was to include session_support=YES in the /etc/pam.d/vsftd configuration file.  So that's the answer to anyone who may have a similar issue.